# How to obtain correct URI of a local file?

Tags: java, file, uri

To my great surprise, following snippet prints `false` on jdk1.8.0_u144

```
public class Tmp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File(".");
    boolean result = f.toPath().toUri().toString().equals(f.toURI().toString());
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
  }
}
```

Obviously, `java.io.File#toURI` and `java.nio.Path#toUri` return different presentations. The question is, which of them is correct (according to [RFC 8089](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089))?

Comment: File.toURI is the correct. You can manually validate by printing both values before comparing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR version: Both forms of the URI are correct according to RFC 8089. 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Your sample code highlights the difference between the value returned by Path's **toUri()** and File's **toURI()** methods for a given file. Printing those to values on my Win10 machine showed:

**path.toUri() => file:///D:/NetBeansProjects/MiscTests/./**

**file.toUri() => file:/D:/NetBeansProjects/MiscTests/./**

The results on Linux are similar:

**path.toUri() => file:///home/johndoe/IdeaProjects/TestUri/./**

**file.toUri() => file:/home/johndoe/IdeaProjects/TestUri/./**

So the only difference is the single or triple forward slashes following "**file:**" in the URI.

From your link, Appendix B of RFC 8089 confirms that both forms are valid URIs:

> A traditional file URI for a local file with an empty authority.
>         This is the most common format in use today.  For example:
>
> ```
>   *  "file:///path/to/file"
> ```
>
> o  The minimal representation of a local file with no authority
>   field
>         and an absolute path that begins with a slash "/".  For example:
>
> ```
>   *  "file:/path/to/file"
> ```

Further confirmation that both URI forms are valid is that either can be entered in a browser to display the content of the directory. However, there are a few points worth noting:

- Brave was the only browser that would not accept the single slash form of the URI (as given by File.toURI().toString()).
- All browsers accepted the triple slash form of the URI (as given by File.toPath().toUri().toString()).
- If I entered the URI in the browser's adddress bar with a single slash it was converted to a triple slash.
- Strangely, both Chrome and Firefox will accept any number of slashes in the URI (e.g. file:///////////D:/NetBeansProjects/MiscTests/), and still display the directory.